# How do I connect with MySQL database from Android application?

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-studio, server-side

I have been researching answers to this question on various platforms but can't quite put the pieces together.

Currently, I have a device hardcoded in C++ that connects to a server and uses a PHP script to input data into a database. From there, I have a PHP script that then connects to the database and taskes the data, creating an XML file. I then have a Google API that takes the XML file and creates markers from the XML files data.

I am now trying to build a Java version of this in my android application. Since the PHP scrips are already on the LAMP server, and the database is already in the tables on the server.

How do I go about connecting to the database from the android studio? 
Is there a way to connect to the server and use my PHP script?

I have never used JSON, and would like to avoid it and stick to PHP where possible.

Thanks!

Comment: If this is a long term project I would suggest rebuilding it completly. For instance with Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP at server side then the only way to connect with database is to use php webservices aka APIs. As you stated you have not used json but thats the only way. To simplify the networking calls, you can use various libraries which will simplify the http requests for you. For android, volley and okhttp are mostly used libraries. I personally suggest you to use volley for android. Json parsing using volley is just a piece of cake

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. Would I be able to make use of my pre-existing php files at all, or would it be a case of entirely re-writing them in JSON?

Comment: Unfortunately NO. You can create your own php files specifically for android which will fetch data from database and will serve in json format.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use webservice here.For simplicity use the retrofit library in android it will take care about your json input/output parsing,webservice calling and handling the response from it.